# How can I zoom an image in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I had an image in image in my iPhone application.  The text in the image is not readable as it is very small.  How can I zoom it at run time?

Anyone please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x, (imageview.frame.origin.y), imageview.frame.size.width + 20, imageview.frame.size.height + 20);
```

OR

```
imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can I scroll it after zooming it?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the image on a ImageView , which is added to the ScrollView. And then you can use the scroll view delegate method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

for zooming and scrolling.